# Open contents of BytesIO in external program

Tags: python-3.x, linux, windows, cross-platform, bytesio

I want a Python3-script (more specifically 3.10+) of mine to open the contents of an in-memory file in an external program, preferably on all platforms (with letting the OS choose the default app for that type, for example a PDF) but if it only works on Windows and in a separate version on Linux it's OK.
I can already use in-memory files with `io.BytesIO` but I'm stuck on

1. getting the file to open in an external program and
2. getting Windows to automatically choose a program which is more easy on Linux with `xdg-open`.

Comment: Just to be clear: I would like to avoid writing the file to disk, even though I would do it if it isn't possible to open an `io.BytesIO` "file" in an external program.

Comment: How can assign such a path to the file (is it system-wide findable if I do it like in the other question you linked)? Can I maybe open that file without touching the hard drive?